Solution of a system of PDEs on a non-uniform grid
I am dealing with the following PDEs:
$$\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial h}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial h}\left(P_{L}+\frac{\zeta}{\nu}\frac{\partial u}{\partial h}\right) $$
With the following Initial/boundary conditions:
$$P_{L}+\frac{\zeta}{\nu}\frac{\partial u}{\partial h}=0$$ at $h=0,M$. Here $h$ is the amount of mass between $x=0$ and $x=X$.The co-ordinate is defined as $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\rho$$
The conservation of mass shows that:
$$dh=\rho_{0}dX=\rho dx$$
So if you have a non-constant initial density, your grid will be non-uniform. I am solving this using the finite volume method, and as a result, I have to find the derivatives on the cell interface. I made the approximation for the derivative as:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial h}\Bigg|_{h_{i}}\approx\frac{u_{i+\frac{1}{2}}-u_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}(\delta h_{i+\frac{1}{2}}+\delta h_{i-\frac{1}{2}})}$$
Is there a way to increase the accuracy for the derivative?

What happens if you write your system of equations in terms of the spatial variable $x$?

From your conservation of mass equation, you are assuming $\rho$ is constant and therefore $h$ is proportional to $x$?
